# How can I do a bit shift for a large sequence of bytes in NASM Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Suppose that I have defined, in `.data`, X amount of bytes:

```
db 00000000b,00100011b,11100011b,...........
```

Let's say that I defined 50 bytes.

I would like to grab those 50 bytes, and do a big bit shift to the left. The example above would then look like this:

```
db 00000000b,01000111b,11000110b,...........
```

This is easy to do when we're working with, say, 4 bytes, because you just put them into `EAX` and do the shift. But now I have 50 bytes.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Shift by how many? You'd want different algorithms for shift by one, by less than 8, and for 8 or more.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: By less than 8 (1 in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shift any number of bytes one bit to the left: First `SHL` the least significant byte one bit. Then `RCL` all other bytes one bit, going from the second least significant to the most significant.

Answer (score 0):

If doing just a single-bit left shift, you can use the rcl instruction to shift one memory word left one bit, capture the carry, and repeat on the next word up. You want to reset the carry for the first iteration.  (I'm pretty sure this isn't NASM syntax, but that shouldn't bother you much).

```
   mov   esi, offset data_buffer
   mov   ebx, data_buffer_dword_count
   lea   esi, [esi+4*ebx-4]
   clc
loop:
   rcl   [esi]
   lea   esi, -4[esi]
   dec   ebx             ; this kind of loop is why dec instructions don't affect carry!
   jne   loop
```

If shifting N>1 bits, this is slow.  In this case, use the shift-left-double instruction.   This instruction uses two registers, and shifts the pair of by a specified distance (cl or some immediate constant).  You need to keep track of partially shifted results; the bookkeeping is a little tricky.

If your shift distance is 31 bits or less, this code should do it:
(Edit: I replaced previous code I had here with something less klunky):

```
   mov   esi, offset data_buffer
   mov   ebx, data_buffer_dword_count
   lea   esi, [esi+4*ebx-4]
   xor   edi, edi        ; bits from last time; this acts like "clc" in above loop
loop:
   mov   eax, [esi]
   xor   edx, edx        ; make 64 bit value of next dword
   mov   ecx, shift_left_distance
   shld  edx, eax, cl    ; shift left across <edx,eax>
   add   eax, edi        ; form full shifted dword by combining with last partial 
   mov   [esi], eax      ; update storage with shifted result
   mov   edi, edx        ; save shifted but unstored bits from this round
   lea   esi, -4[esi]
   dec   ebx
   jne   loop
```

If you want to shift more than 31 bits, then you have combine the ideas of shuffling dwords by using memory offsets (of shift distance in dwords divided by 32) with the above scheme for the shift distance modulo 32.

Comment: isn't `or` a better alternative to `add` to combine bits?

Comment: does it matter? The target bits are zero.

Comment: I'm old school.  I started on a machine that had ADD and AND but not OR.  Old habits die hard :-}

Comment: I started on Z80, luxury car of old times :)

Comment: Check out PDP-8s if you want to see the Edsel of old times.

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is a flavor of shift that shifts in or through the carry bit.  The carry bit is used to take the shift out of one shift operation and use that to shift in on the next.  So if shifting left you would start with the lsbyte, its msbit shifts out, and is shifted in to the right of the next to lsbyte and so on, creating a cascade effect across all the bytes.  I will leave it to the reader to look up the shift operations and see which ones do what.  Remember your first shift operation you need to control the shift in, so clear the carry bit or use a different instruction.  Often the shift through carry is called rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Shifting an array of bytes left by one bit is best achieved with add + adc sequence -- you can combine any length of operations, such as:

```
lea edi, [array]
mov eax, [edi]
mov bx,  [edi + 4]
mov cl,  [edi + 6]

add eax, eax        ;; shift the MSB to Carry bit
adc bx, bx          ;; shift the previous carry to bit 0 + produce new carry
adc cl, cl

mov [edi], eax      ;; write back
mov [edi + 4], bx
mov [edi + 6], cl
```